# Query CRM data in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I am building a silverlight app for CRM 2011 and I was wondering what the best way to retrieve data from the CRM system is.

I have linked in my organisation as a service reference and am able to access that. I have seen a few different ways to retrieve data but they all seem rather complicated. Is there anything like what we can use in plugins such as a fetch XMl query or a simple Service.Retrieve method?

Thanks

Comment: When you attempt to use Service. Retrieve call, what happens?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Is your Silverlight app being deployed as WebResource?

Comment: I haven't actually tried putting in a service.retrieve yet, I wasn't sure of the references needed or if the code was the same for a plugin. Yeah it is, I'm aiming to show it as a pop up from a ribbon button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am will suggest you to use [Silvercrmsoap](http://silvercrmsoap.codeplex.com/documentation) , it's very easy to use. I have used this in my silverlight projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a service reference to your project you can use LINQ to query the datasets. 
You can download the CSDL from Developer Resources under the customisation area.

```
private FelineSoftContext context;
private System.String serverUrl;
private DataServiceCollection<SalesOrder> _orders;

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serverUrl = (String)GetContext().Invoke("getServerUrl");
        //Remove the trailing forward slash returned by CRM Online
        //So that it is always consistent with CRM On Premises
        if (serverUrl.EndsWith("/"))
            serverUrl = serverUrl.Substring(0, serverUrl.Length - 1);

        Uri ODataUri = new Uri(serverUrl + "/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/", UriKind.Absolute);
        context = new FelineSoftContext(ODataUri) { IgnoreMissingProperties = true };

        var orders = from ord in context.SalesOrderSet
                     orderby ord.Name
                     select new SalesOrder
                     {
                         Name = ord.Name,
                         SalesOrderId = ord.SalesOrderId
                     };

        _orders = new DataServiceCollection<SalesOrder>();
        _orders.LoadCompleted += _orders_LoadCompleted;
        _orders.LoadAsync(orders);
    }

    void _orders_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (_orders.Continuation != null)
            {
                _orders.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                OrderLookup.ItemsSource = _orders;
                OrderLookup.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
                OrderLookup.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
            }
        }
    }
```

You will also need to add a method in your class as below:

```
private static ScriptObject GetContext()
    {
        ScriptObject xrmProperty = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
        if (null == xrmProperty)
        {
            //It may be that the global context should be used
            try
            {

                ScriptObject globalContext = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("GetGlobalContext");

                return globalContext;
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Property \"Xrm\" is null and the Global Context is not available.");
            }

        }

        ScriptObject pageProperty = (ScriptObject)xrmProperty.GetProperty("Page");
        if (null == pageProperty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Property \"Xrm.Page\" is null");
        }

        ScriptObject contextProperty = (ScriptObject)pageProperty.GetProperty("context");
        if (null == contextProperty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Property \"Xrm.Page.context\" is null");
        }

        return contextProperty;
    }
```

You will need to add an additional class library and put the following code within it. Change the class name to match the Context you exported:

```
partial class FelineSoftContext
{

    #region Methods
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.ReadingEntity += this.OnReadingEntity;
        this.WritingEntity += this.OnWritingEntity;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers
    private void OnReadingEntity(object sender, ReadingWritingEntityEventArgs e)
    {
        ODataEntity entity = e.Entity as ODataEntity;
        if (null == entity)
        {
            return;
        }

        entity.ClearChangedProperties();
    }

    private void OnWritingEntity(object sender, ReadingWritingEntityEventArgs e)
    {
        ODataEntity entity = e.Entity as ODataEntity;
        if (null == entity)
        {
            return;
        }

        entity.RemoveUnchangedProperties(e.Data);
        entity.ClearChangedProperties();
    }
    #endregion
}

public abstract class ODataEntity
{
    private readonly Collection<string> ChangedProperties = new Collection<string>();

    public ODataEntity()
    {
        EventInfo info = this.GetType().GetEvent("PropertyChanged");
        if (null != info)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler method = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(this.OnEntityPropertyChanged);

            //Ensure that the method is not attached and reattach it
            info.RemoveEventHandler(this, method);
            info.AddEventHandler(this, method);
        }
    }

    #region Methods
    public void ClearChangedProperties()
    {
        this.ChangedProperties.Clear();
    }

    internal void RemoveUnchangedProperties(XElement element)
    {
        const string AtomNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
        const string DataServicesNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
        const string DataServicesMetadataNamespace = DataServicesNamespace + "/metadata";

        if (null == element)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        List<XElement> properties = (from c in element.Elements(XName.Get("content", AtomNamespace)
                                               ).Elements(XName.Get("properties", DataServicesMetadataNamespace)).Elements()
                                     select c).ToList();

        foreach (XElement property in properties)
        {
            if (!this.ChangedProperties.Contains(property.Name.LocalName))
            {
                property.Remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnEntityPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.ChangedProperties.Contains(e.PropertyName))
        {
            this.ChangedProperties.Add(e.PropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```